# dialog com problema ao usar --item-help

Tags: linux, dialog

Estou enfrentando problemas ao implementar um *checkbox* com `dialog`, no Linux Mint.

O que ocorre é que se utilizo a opção `--item-help`, o *box* monta os `checkbox` errado.

```
dialog --title 'Seleção dos Componentes' --checklist 'O que você quer instalar?' 0 0 0 syntax 'Arquivos de sintaxe' off mouse 'Suporte a mouse' off color 'Suporte a cores' on beep 'Driver avançado de som' off
```

O código acima funciona como o esperado.

Porém, se adiciono `--item-help`, o `dialog` simplesmente esquece "mouse".

```
dialog --item-help --title 'Seleção dos Componentes' --checklist 'O que você quer instalar?' 0 0 0 syntax 'Arquivos de sintaxe' off mouse 'Suporte a mouse' off color 'Suporte a cores' on beep 'Driver avançado de som' off
```

A versão do `dialog` que estou usando é *1.3-20160209*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque `--item-help` reconhece "mouse" como texto de ajuda do primeiro `checkbox`.

É necessário especificar o texto de ajuda para cada `checkbox`.

```
dialog --title 'Seleção dos Componentes' --item-help --checklist 'O que você quer instalar?' 0 0 0 syntax 'Arquivos de sintaxe' off 'Arquivos de sintaxse'  mouse 'Suporte a mouse' off 'Suporte a mouse'  color 'Suporte a cores' on 'Suporte a cores'  beep 'Driver avançado de som' off 'Driver avançado de som'
```

Se preferir colocar as informações num `array`:

```
items=(
    syntax "Arquivos de sintaxe" off "Arquivos de sintaxe"
    mouse "Suporte a mouse"  off "Suporte a mouse"
    color "Suporte a cores"  on  "Suporte a cores"
    beep  "Driver avançado de som" off "Driver avançado de som"
)

dialog --title 'Seleção dos Componentes' --item-help --checklist 'O que você quer instalar?' 0 0 0 "${items[@]}"
```

Veja o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema foi que na documentação esse parâmetro não está muito bem claro (para mim, pelo menos). Valeu pela resposta.